# how can i make a responsive menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I have a question about a simple menu with bootstrap for a mobile device. 
Now lets go:

This Picture displayed a Example, how i wish me my menu. The Desktop Menu is program like this: 
http://cameronspear.com/demos/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/

But i dont implement the mobile menu like the picture. How can i realise it with bootstrap from a simple dropdown left to a list menu right?

Tanks for help =) 
 Here the picture:
http://goo.gl/fHeSCd

Comment: This happens automatically. Look here for examples: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Thanks for help, but i know this website. So, i programm the Navbar with hover dropdown and i add a button.navbar-toggle. Ok, but my problem is, that my menu dont show like the mockup picture, its look like my programmed hover drowpdown menu. i will a list, have somebody a example with the dropdownmenu?